# table relationship connection causing error

Tags: c#, sql

[image]

I figured the error is caused by the relationship between table `Produksi` and `DetailProduksi`, because when I tried to delete the connection completely, it runs without a problem.

But I've been trying stuff for around 2 hours only to figure out the problem and not the solution.

[relationship connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYcEO.png)

Please tell me if more information is required to help me

edit:
i figured it out. the problem was not at the relationship itself, but at the code of my program. so it seems inserting into the 'produksi' table first instead of the 'DetailProduksi' first mattered. newb mistake i guess.

Comment: Do you have a row in the `Produksi` table with the corresponding key? If not - you should add a row with the corresponding key into the `Produksi` table first.

Comment: This is an error of foreign key reference means you are inserting whatever id_produksi is not available in dbo.Produksi.

Comment: ^ yes i do. it's the primary key from the 'produksi' table(as primary) connect to the primary key do 'DetailProduksi'(as foreign)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably inserting data in DetailProduksi table with a forign key value that does not exist in Produksi table. Please check if the value(FK) that points the id(PK) is present.